SQL Server replication dist latency: building up to 1 sec, then dropping to zero - why?
I'm testing a new transactional replication setup on a SQL Server 2022.
It's a push replication with only 20 tables, averaging 20 cmds/sec. It is working, but I'm seeing a strange wave pattern in the distribution latency:

The red line in the chart represents cmds/sec, and the black line represents distribution latency. The latency grows from zero to around 1 second, then drops back to zero again. Why?
My initial suspicion was the disk system, but I see no latency, no queues building up, etc. There is also no latency on the log reader. These are the agent settings on the distributor:

Any suggestions?
EDIT
The pattern actually seems to be the same in production, even though the waves are narrower:

